# Outputting Formatted NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, formatting

```
UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[[LanguageManager sharedLanguageManager] get:@"Notice"]
                                                  message:[NSString stringWithFormat:[[LanguageManager sharedLanguageManager] get:@"Notice_Text"]]
                                                 delegate:nil
                                        cancelButtonTitle:[[LanguageManager sharedLanguageManager] get:@"Close"]
                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

Hi, let me explain my codes above. Basically it calls up an `UIAlertView` with data read from a `.plist` via my LanguageManager singleton class. The LanguageManager get function basically returns a `NSString*`. I know I should use the `NSLocalizedString` class but I had been using this class for a while now, so I had decided to stick to it.

My problem lies with the "message:" parameter. The string I am trying to read contains formatting characters like `\n` but it does not output correctly and appears as `\n` instead of a line break when printed. I also get the "Format string is not a string literal" warning. Other parts of the app using similar method to return a string which contains `%d` or `%f` works correctly though, just the `'\n'` character not working.

Does anyone have any idea how I may overcome this?

Comment: for string, you use %@  `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[LanguageManager sharedLanguageManager] get:@"Notice_Text"]]`

Comment: Hi janusfidel, but if the string contains "\n" it still doesnt newline correctly, it outputs the "\n" as a string instead.

let's say [[LanguageManager sharedLanguageManager] get:@"Notice_Text"]] = @"First line text\nSecond line text\nThird Line";

Comment: where are you @"Notice_Text" coming from?

Comment: LanguageManager is my self written class to read text from a .plist (before i realized the existence of NSLocalizeString). The "get" function is as follows
`-(NSString*)get:(NSString*)key
{
 NSArray *textLangArray = [dict objectForKey:key];
 NSString *text = [textLangArray objectAtIndex:curLang];
 
 if(!text)
  text = key;

  
 return text;
}`

Comment: It should work with `\n`. Some use `\r\n`. There must be something wrong with your `[LanguageManager sharedLanguageManager] get:@"Notice_Text"]`. Check its contents thoroughly during debugging. Try NSLog the content or the message property. You may find out that the `\n` is escaped with an additional ``\` or `'` or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"\n" is *not* a "formatting character": the compiler translates it to the appropiate code; the string NEVER contains the "\" and "n" characters.

Thus, if you string comes from a source that is NOT compiled by a (Objective-)C(++) compiler, "\n" will be just the two characters. Nothing will turn them into a newline, unless you do it yourself with something like

```
NewString=[MyString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\n" withString:@"\n"];
```

Note the two different strings: in the first case, "\" prevents the compiler from doing the \n -> newline conversion, while the second string will be an actual newline.

The warning about a non-literal format string is somewhat pointless; I've yet to find a good way to get rid of that one (for now, I just disable it entirely, using -Wno-format-nonliteral on clang++ >= 4.0).